fcitx floating panel disappeared
I don't know what exactly happened but my fcitx input method floating panel is no longer showing.  It used to look like this (on the lower right corner):

The input method is still working perfectly (I am using fcitx-sunpinyin Chinese input), and I can see the character suggestions etc.  It's just that the floating panel (which indicates which input method I'm using) disappeared.
When I open the options ConfigureFcitx --> Appearance, the window is empty, saying "No configuration option for Kimpanel".  In some answers, I have seen people say there is an option to show or hide the panel.
I used to be able to locate the panel by, for example:
> pgrep -x fcitx
6487
> xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid 6487
(used to return a window ID, now nothing)
> xdotool search --pid 6487
2097155
....

Now xdotool only returns a list of windows if I leave out the --onlyvisible option.  Which suggests the window may have become "invisible" or no longer exists.
The possible causes of this problem:

maybe an upgrade? since I have not rebooted for some days
maybe because I installed a screen-drawing tool called gromit-mpx which may use XWayland.  I'm using Lubuntu with LXDE desktop, if that matters.


I found the solution:
sudo apt remove fcitx-ui-qimpanel

I found out the cause when I did fcitx-qimpanel and it gave an error message about /tmp/fcitx-qimpanel\:0.pid being locked.  And then I did a cat of that file and killed the process, my original IM panel reappeared.
I guess an update automatically installed fcitx-ui-qimpanel.
